# How do I get rid of the second block in this DIV

Tags: vuetify.js, algolia, vue-instant-search

I’ve got to be missing something.

Can anyone advise how to get rid of the block on the right ([SEE SCREENSHOT)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8osh.png)? I simply want the search box display the full width and some reason (I can’t figure out why) it’s compacted in the block on the left.

```js
<v-row>
  <v-col>
     <ais-instant-search :search-client="searchClient" index-name="brands_index">
        <ais-configure :hitsPerPage="5" />
        <ais-autocomplete>
          <div slot-scope="{ indices }">
            <v-autocomplete
              placeholder="Type your brand name here..."
              v-model="brand"
              filled
              :items="indicesToSuggestions(indices)"
            />
            <v-autocomplete label="Components" :items="components"></v-autocomplete>
          </div>
        </ais-autocomplete>
     </ais-instant-search>
   </v-col>
 </v-row>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... in case anyone else runs into the same issue - watch out for this guy in your style tag.  I must have copied it from an example and forgot about it.

```
.ais-InstantSearch {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
    grid-gap: 1em;
}
```